# use same job in different view in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have one job and I using this job two different views.It's posssible but I want to change job's configuration.For example,
View1 :Job1  ,Job2
View2 :  Job1, Job3
In view1 Job1 svn conf:http://192.168.x.x/newsvn/sf/branch/aa/Job1/
In view2 Job1 svn conf:http://192.168.x.x/newsvn/sf/trunk/Job1/

i want configure like this.How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible to have this dynamic behaviour.

But you can use the [Template Project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) to create a master template which will define the main job configuration.

Next, you create 2 "child" jobs which have their own SVN configuration.

Comment: I didn't changed svn Repository URL when choose Use SCM from another project :( it doesnt work for me :(

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have 2 different SCM configuration for the same job? With the Template Project plugin, you can define a parent project which define all the configuration except the SCM one. Next, on the children, you just have to configure the SCM section. But you will have to create 2 child jobs... Not sure it will solve your problem...

Comment: Bruno,Thanks a lot for your answer .We decided to change configuration :)